# What does this syntax mean in C++: `[](){ some code here }`?

Tags: c++

I haven't seen this syntax before, can someone explain me please?

```
std::array<int, 8> heights;
std::generate(begin(heights), end(heights), [](){ int x; std::cin >> x; return x;});
```

Comment: Look up *lambda expressions*.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: Question title got the syntax out of order. Be sure about what you're unsure of.